# Expected value of a random operator

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, expectation

Suppose that $X$ is a random element with values in a separable Hilbert space $\mathbb H$ such that $\operatorname E\|X\|^2<\infty$. The expected value of $X$ is defined as a unique $\mu\in\mathbb H$ such that $$\operatorname E\langle x,X\rangle=\langle x,\mu\rangle$$ for each $x\in\mathbb H$ (the existence and uniqueness of such an element follows from the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem)).

I am trying to understand the definition of the covariance operator of $X$. Usually, the covariance operator of $X$ is defined as $$\operatorname E[(X-\mu)\otimes(X-\mu)],$$
where $\mu$ is the expected value of $X$ and $x\otimes x:\mathbb H\to\mathbb H$ with $x\in\mathbb H$ denotes an operator defined by $(x\otimes x)(y)=\langle y,x\rangle x$ for each $y\in\mathbb H$. So $(X-\mu)\otimes(X-\mu)$ is a random operator and $\operatorname E[(X-\mu)\otimes(X-\mu)]$ is the expected value of a random operator. How is the expected value of this random operator defined?

Answer (score 2):

Since you defined the expected value as a linear functional, via  $\langle x,\mu\rangle := \operatorname E\langle x,X\rangle$, you can similarly define the covariance as a sesquilinear form, 
$$
B(x, y) = \operatorname{E}\left(\langle x, X-\mu\rangle \langle X-\mu, y\rangle \right)
$$
This is evidently bounded: $|B(x,y)|\le C\|x\|\|y\|$ where $C =
 \operatorname{E}\|X-\mu\|^2$. So there is a bounded operator $T$ such that $B(x, y) = \langle Tx, y\rangle$, and this is the covariance in operator form.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the expected value of a random vector. If $X$ is a random <strike>vector</strike> operator then its expected value is the unique operator $T$ such that $\mathbb{E} \langle v, X w\rangle = \langle v, T w\rangle$ for all $v,w \in \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: This does not make any sense. $X$ is a random vector, but its expected value is an operator $T$?.. If $X$ is a random vector and $w\in\mathbb H$, how is $Xw$ defined?

Comment: It's just a typo, of course $X$ is a random operator.